# Identify stocks with same feature values using a np.array_equal() function in a nested loop

Tags: python, nested-loops, feature-clustering

I would like to understand if my code is working correctly.

The dataframe, df2 is a vertically stacked time series of a stock's feature.

| stock_id | log_target_vol_corr_32_clusters_stnd |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.4 |
| 1 | 0.8 |
| 1 | 0.7 |
| 2 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.4 |
| 2 | 0.0 |
| 3 | 0.4 |
| 3 | 0.8 |
| 3 | 0.7 |
| 4 | 0.9 |
| 4 | 0.9 |
| 4 | 0.1 |
| 5 | 0.9 |
| 5 | 0.9 |
| 5 | 0.1 |

Notice that stocks (1 & 3) and (4 & 5)  have the same feature values therefore I want to group them together into a cluster. Ultimately, I want to find all the stock ids belonging to each cluster.

```
## find stock ids of clusters having same feature values
column = 'log_target_vol_corr_32_clusters_stnd'
remaining_stocks = df2['stock_id'].unique().astype(int)
clusters = {}
for s in remaining_stocks:
    print(s)
    clusters[s] = []
    a1 = df2[df2['stock_id'] == s ][column]
    remaining_stocks = np.delete(remaining_stocks,np.where(remaining_stocks==s))
    for s1 in remaining_stocks:
        a2 = df2[df2['stock_id'] == s1 ][column]
        if np.array_equal(a1,a2):
            print(s1)
            remaining_stocks = np.delete(remaining_stocks,np.where(remaining_stocks==s1))
            clusters[s].append(s1)
            print(remaining_stocks)
```

Could you please explain what is the error in this code?

I wrote the following code and seem to get more than the actual numbers of clusters in the dataframe.

Comment: IMO if you are providing a set of time series, it would be a good idea to further tag each result with the time in addition to the series ID.

Comment: In addition, it is unlikely that in this case you can rely on the equality of two floats. What if the difference between two numbers is negligible?

Comment: @Vitalizzare, thanks for your reply. I omitted the time column for simplicity. Hmm, actually the floats are exactly equal. This is guaranteed. My question is with the logic. Is my programming logic wrong? If I wrote this in another language will I get correct results? Ultimately, I used kmeans clustering because I know the number of clusters is 32.